# Exception in SQL query

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am trying to insert a query as string in the database table. But I am getting an exception

> Incorrect syntax near 'p101'

Code:

```vb
str = "Select cnum,email from empdb,expdb,edu,propdb where ecode=eno and ecode=enumb and pnum=pcode and pcode='p101'"
Dim dialresult As DialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Sure", "Some Title", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)
If dialresult = DialogResult.Yes Then
    ' s = InputBox("Enter a name")
    s = InputBox("en", "save", "titl1")

    com = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO SaveQuery(qname,fullquery) VALUES ('" + s + "','" + str + "')", con)
    com.ExecuteNonQuery()
    com.Dispose()
End If
```

Comment: Add another set of ' ' around the string literal p101 in the select so its `=''p101''`.  It's escaping the insert command in `com`.  That said, this *could* be opening you to a sql injection attack depending on how you build that `str` value... be careful.

Comment: Since you are doing pass through sql you will have to escape your single quotes with two single quotes. I would suggest using a stored procedure for this. The way you have this coded is not only more difficult it is also vulnerable to sql injection.

Comment: heh seems you got nearly the same answer a few seconds apart.

Comment: NO! **Don't escape single quotes for this.** Use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/)